# How signal mapping in gr-phosphor works

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, gnuradio

My idea is to write a spectrum analyzer using USRP N 210. Here is my graphics for the spectrum.
[image]

I want to add a function that is used in gr - phosphor. More precisely, as I understand it, the spectrogram is displayed. But I don’t understand how it works and which way to look. I would appreciate any guidance[image]

Comment: Do you just want a spectrogram that looks like that displayed by fosphor, or do you want to implement your color scheme in fosphor? Fosphor is a pretty impressive thing, as it does the signal analysis, logarithmic mapping, color mapping and graphical buffer fill all on the GPU.

Comment: I want just such a graphic display. It’s not really important for me what the colors will be. I’m interested in how the signal is detailed in the color form, as I understand it. Fft use just 1024 points. In addition, fft is running on the FPGA USRP N210. Yes gr-phosphor really impressive weight so I at least partially want to repeat it first, even on the CPU

Answer (score 0):

For pyqtgraph, my approach would be to use `numpy.fft` to generate a 2D array of spectrogram data and display that with an `ImageItem`.

Vispy has an oscilloscope + spectrogram demo here: https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/master/examples/demo/scene/oscilloscope.py. The `update` function at the bottom shows how the spectrogram frames are generated.

Comment: You mean that in gr-phosphor, when displaying a spectrum, several readings are simply displayed at the same time with just different colors?

Comment: By the way, Vispy is a very interesting library, I wish I had seen it before. But I will keep it in mind for the following projects. But for this hardware there is already a laptop and unfortunately there is no normal GPU.

Comment: Oh! On closer inspection, it looks like the spectrogram is represented as a series of densely-packed line plots, with one line per frequency band; is that correct?

Comment: You probably mean a waterfall. But I want to achieve just detail on the spectrum and not on the waterfall. That is, to show the curvature of the peak of the signal. This is important for my observations. And in gr-fosphor it is in any way realized. And I want to understand how. Maybe you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, the bit you circled in the question looks like a waterfall plot to me (pyqtgraph's `examples/MultiPlotSpeedTest.py` would be a good start toward that).. but perhaps I don't understand what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Phosphor is showing two plots at once: the real-time FFT (power vs frequency) in the top panel and the spectrogram (frequency vs time with color=power) in the bottom panel.  As time passes, instantaneous views on the top panel become the horizontal cross-section of the bottom plot.  This is kind of like how a water crests over a waterfall.

Your plot seems to be doing the same thing.  I think the only difference is that the magnitude (y-axis on top panel and color on bottom panel) is in linear scale in your plot instead of log scale for your phosphor.

The only other thing to note about the Phosphor is that it is showing some history of power in the real-time FFT plot.  Frequencies that consistently have power in them, will have more opacity and warmer colors.

You can see in your screenshot that there are some blue bands in the plot, this indicates that signals have been seen in those frequencies and at those power levels more than areas that are black.

Moreover, the orange/red colors in the low-power (noise-floor) region of the FFT indicate that there are many time slices where that power level is observed in that frequency.  So, the color is in some ways encoding a moving window probability density function of the power for each frequency bin.